# Is it is possible to make radio group readonly in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I would like to if it is possible to make radio group readonly in Angular.

Comment: Why not disabled ?

Comment: @Vega disabled removes the field from the formGroup's value. readonly (when it's available) just blocks edition

Answer (score 1):

The Radio button not allowed to used **"Readonly"** attributed. Instead you can used 
**"Disabled"** attributed for Disabled or Readonly.

HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="example_6" value="4" disabled="true">
```

or you can used Angular Way with Form Group to disable

```
this.myForm.get('Example').disable();
```

Comment: it's still possible to achieve a readonly-like effect. this is not a solution, but an alternative

Answer (score 0):

disable will lose the value of the radio, so that's not what we want.

There is no elegant method to make it readonly.
Just recover the change with the old value programmatically, like this.

```js
oldValue = getInitialOldValueFromServerOrWhatEver();

onChange(event: MatRadioChange, oldValue: someType) {
  if (someCondition) {
    this.yourForm.get('yourRadioGroupFormControlName').patchValue(event.value);
  } else {
    this.yourForm.get('yourRadioGroupFormControlName').patchValue(oldValue);
    // provide some info
    alert('This can not be changed');    
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-radio-group formControlName="yourRadioGroupFormControlName" (change)="onChange($event, oldValue)">
```

Comment: yours seems to be the best answer yet, however using template-driven normally will solve this while keeping things elegant. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

in your style file (`.css` or `.scss`) file add the following style to the `mat-radio-button` tag as follow:

> .radio-btn {   pointer-events: none; }

Then assign this staying class to the `mat-radio-button` tag in your `.HTML` file as follows:

```
<input type="radio" name="example_6" value="4" class="radio-btn">
```

Comment: isn't the field is still accessible with tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Using a **template-driven** form, the read-only effect can be achieved very easily. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/forms)'s a tutorial. It won't use `disabled` on a field, but it will put fields inside `*ngIf`s, which - like `disabled` - removes the field from the `formGroup`'s `value`.

```html
<form ngForm>
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="viewModel.type" name=type [disabled]="radioDisabled">
        <!-- ... -->
    </mat-radio-group>

    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

```
@Component({ /*...*/ })
export class Component {
  radioDisabled = true;

  viewModel = {
    type: null,
    size: "Small",
  }
}
```

In this component, the `viewModel`'s value will never be affected by the `disabled` attribute, which behaviourally is the same as a `readonly` attribute in an input. It will just block edition without affecting your main view model object. It still will affect the `form.value`, though.